# Showing Percentage and Total In stacked Bar Chart of chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js, bar-chart

I am working on stacked Bar charts using chart.js.
I need to show labels in middle of Bars as percentage and total sum on top of bars stacked together. Currently, I am able to show their percentage after searching for code. But that percentages are not correct mathematically. I have added that code in js fiddle. Hope I got some help for it. I am just weak in js.
https://jsfiddle.net/n4nish/hca3wdgq/4/

HTML -

```
  var data = [{
     label: 'New',
     backgroundColor: '#1d3f74',
     data: [6310, 5742, 4044, 5564]
        }, {
     label: 'Repeat',
     backgroundColor: '#6c92c8',
     data: [11542, 12400, 12510, 11450]
        }];


 var options = {
     maintainAspectRatio: false,
     spanGaps: false,
     responsive: true,
     legend: {
         display: true,
         position: 'bottom',
         labels: {
             fontColor: "#fff",
             boxWidth: 14,
             fontFamily: 'proximanova'
         }
     },
     tooltips: {
         mode: 'label',
         callbacks: {
             label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                 var type = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                 var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                 var total = 0;
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
                     total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];
                 if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex !== data.datasets.length - 1) {
                     return type + " : " + value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '1,');
                 } else {
                     return [type + " : " + value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '1,'), "Overall : " + total];
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     plugins: {
         datalabels: {
             formatter: function (value, ctx) {
                 let sum = 0;
                 let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                 dataArr.map(data => {
                     sum += data;
                 });
                 let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(0) + "%";
                 return percentage;
             },
             font: {
                 weight: "normal"
             },
             color: "#fff"
         }
     },
     scales: {
         xAxes: [{
             stacked: true,
             gridLines: {
                 display: false
             },
             ticks: {
                 fontColor: "#fff"
             }
                }],
         yAxes: [{
             stacked: true,
             display: false,
             ticks: {
                 fontColor: "#fff"
             }
                }]
     }

 };

 var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart").getContext('2d');

 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: ["Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sept"],
         datasets: data
     },
     options: options
 });
```

Comment: Do you want to show the sum in the dark blue part and percentage in the light blue part?

Comment: Hi, No Actually I want to show percentage in both light blue and dark blue. Total number should be on top of that.
You can see percentage is already there but it is giving wrong result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set options that will apply to:

all labels in the chart:
`options.plugins.datalabels.*`

only a single dataset:
`dataset.datalabels.*`

```js
// Label formatter function
const formatter = (value, ctx) => {
  const otherDatasetIndex = ctx.datasetIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
  const total =
    ctx.chart.data.datasets[otherDatasetIndex].data[ctx.dataIndex] + value;

  return `${(value / total * 100).toFixed(0)}%`;
};

const data = [{
    // stack: 'test',
    label: "New",
    backgroundColor: "#1d3f74",
    data: [6310, 5742, 4044, 5564],
    // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
    datalabels: {
      color: "white",
      formatter: formatter
    }
  },
  {
    // stack: 'test',
    label: "Repeat",
    backgroundColor: "#6c92c8",
    data: [11542, 12400, 12510, 11450],
    // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
    datalabels: {
      color: "yellow",
      formatter: formatter
    }
  }
];

const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  spanGaps: false,
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: "bottom",
    labels: {
      fontColor: "#fff",
      boxWidth: 14,
      fontFamily: "proximanova"
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: "label",
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        const type = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        const value =
          data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        let total = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
          total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];
        if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex !== data.datasets.length - 1) {
          return (
            type + " : " + value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "1,")
          );
        } else {
          return [
            type +
            " : " +
            value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "1,"),
            "Overall : " + total
          ];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
    datalabels: {
      color: "#white",
      align: "center"
    }
  },
  scales: {

    xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#fff"
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'category',
        offset: true,
        position: 'top',
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#fff",
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return data[0].data[index] + data[1].data[index]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      display: false,
      ticks: {
        fontColor: "#fff"
      }
    }]
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("mychart").getContext("2d");

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sept"],
    datasets: data
  },
  options: options
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#mychart {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.4.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/PXxywK)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Actually this is not what I had wanted.
What I am trying it, Let's say in first bar,
I want to show percentage out of 100%. First bottom one is showing 29%, upper one should show 71%. Total number of users will be shown on top.
I am trying myself too. If I find something. I will post the code here too.

Comment: I have made a small edit to the formatter. Let me know if it is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, really thanks for helping me out. One last thing if possible.
Can we put total value which is reflecting on 'Overall' on top of bars?My problem is that I am not good with its syntax at all. May be if you can show total value over top of light bar and then move it up?

Comment: Which total do you need? Light blue plus dark blue?

Comment: Yes. Light blue + Dark blue. 
Example - First bar has total numbers = 17852.
This number should be shown on top. Actually, tooltip will be hidden too. That's why total numbers needed.
Also, One more thing. Can you make this chart specific instead of generic? Actually, I am using other area chart too and it looks little messed up. I think cons formatter is a culprit for it.

Comment: Nevermind for 2nd question. I have hidden labels on that graph. So, all is good for other graph now. :)

Comment: Where do you want to show that total number? On top of what?

Comment: Thanks for the pic. I've made another edit. Next time add a pic like that from the beginning if you can :)

Comment: Thank you very much for solving it. :)
Yeah, next time I will keep that in mind regarding providing image. :)
One little thing if possible. How can we remove those horizontal lines below xaxis? It is common for both months and total numbers. I removed vertical lines by gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186610/discussion-between-ksav-and-nishant-sharma).

Comment: Any suggestion for same height  all bars (actually full height for total 100 percent)?