# ChartJS, make the bars show correct percentage?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following chart that shows some data and their percentage, the percentage part is referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161939/showing-percentage-and-total-in-stacked-bar-chart-of-chart-js).

It only works properly for the first bar from left for each person and the other bars don't have proper percentages shown, how can I fix this?

It uses datalabels plugin and sets things up in the formatter. I know it's happening in the const otherDatasetIndex and const total but having a hard time to revise the code to what I need.

New to ChartJs. Any help is appreciated.

```js
const trend_options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      formatter: function(value, ctx) {
const otherDatasetIndex = ctx.datasetIndex % 2 === 0 ? ctx.datasetIndex + 1 : ctx.datasetIndex - 1;
        const total = ctx.chart.data.datasets[otherDatasetIndex].data[ctx.dataIndex] + value;
        return `${(value / total * 100).toFixed()}%`;
      },

      font: {
        weight: "bold"
      },
      color: "#fff",
      display: function(context) {
        let index = context.dataIndex;
        let value = context.dataset.data[index];
        return value > 0; // display labels with a value greater than 0
      }
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
      suggestedMax: 15,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 5,
      }
    }
  },
};


const app_data_trend = [{
    label: 'App Month 1 TW',
    data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4],
    backgroundColor: '#007bff',
    stack: 'Stack 0',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 1 jira',
    data: [3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3],
    backgroundColor: '#6DB526',
    stack: 'Stack 0',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 2 TW',
    data: [4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4],
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    stack: 'Stack 1',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 2 jira',
    data: [4, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    stack: 'Stack 1',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 3 TW',
    data: [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3],
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    stack: 'Stack 2',
  },
  {
    label: 'App Month 3 jira',
    data: [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5],
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    stack: 'Stack 2',
  },

]

const ctx8 = document.getElementById("tsa-applications-trending");
const chart8 = new Chart(ctx8, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4'],
    datasets: app_data_trend
  },
  options: trend_options,
});
```

```css
.chart-container{
position: relative; height:80vh; width:80vw
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="tsa-applications-trending"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with the following line:

```
const otherDatasetIndex = ctx.datasetIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

This will always use the first dataset to compare against. There are 6 total datasets and you want compare sets of two. The below code should fix this.

```
const otherDatasetIndex = ctx.datasetIndex % 2 === 0 ? ctx.datasetIndex + 1 : ctx.datasetIndex - 1;
```

This will compare all even datasets with the odd dataset just after it and all odd data sets with the even dataset coming before it in the array.