# How to customize percentage label in Doughnutchart ng2 chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

In Doughnut chart that value of percentage should be customized like this

[This is my doughnut chart look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mafs.png)

Is there any way for doing this in ng2 charts?

There are my code I used

```
public barChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [20,20,30] }
  ];
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plugins: {
      labels: false
    },
    showLines: false,
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
  };
  public doughnutChartColors2: Array<any> = [{
    backgroundColor: ['#58dfa7']

  }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values to percentage and then format the data with `%` and pass it to the chart. Or you can use plugin like this, [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/a1Lvn4eb/43/)

```
var options = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                let sum = 0;
                let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                dataArr.map(data => {
                    sum += data;
                });
                let percentage = (value*100 / sum).toFixed(2)+"%";
                return percentage;
            },
            color: '#fff',
        }
    }
};
```

Refer [Show Percentile values in DoughnutChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044013/chartjs-datalabels-show-percentage-value-in-pie-piece) . Happy Coding!!

Comment: what is ctx means?

Comment: For me this code is not working i used ng2 charts.js

Comment: @MadMac https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/a1Lvn4eb/7/ Try this. I checked again. The solution above works.